# Purpose of __init__.py. Or: Why put code in __init__.py instead of a module?

Tags: python, django

I am reviewing Django's code. It has these packages:

```
➜  django pwd
/Users/ugur/.virtualenvs/evernote/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django
➜  django tree -L 1
.
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── __pycache__
├── apps
├── bin
├── conf
├── contrib
├── core
├── db
├── dispatch
├── forms
├── http
├── middleware
├── shortcuts.py
├── template
├── templatetags
├── test
├── urls
├── utils
└── views
```

Now I dived into the package in `db/` and try to understand the structure.

Classes that I use very often when I create my models are for instance:

- `models.CharField`
- `models.TextField`
- `models.IntegerField`

In trying to review their code, I was surprised to find them in:

`db/models/fields/__init__.py`

Looking into that `__init__.py` file, I find >2300 lines of code.

I was using `__init__.py` files to indicate to the interpreter that a folder is meant to be a package consisting of modules.

Also, checking attributes of an object via `dir(myobject)` I can see that the `__file__` attribute points to `__init__.py` file. For example `dir(django)`:

```
In [5]: dir(django)
Out[5]:
['VERSION',
'__builtins__',
'__cached__',
'__doc__',
'__file__',
'__loader__',
'__name__',
'__package__',
'__path__',
'__spec__',
'__version__',
'get_version',
'setup', 'utils']


## so `django.__file__` equals to ./django/__init__.py` 
##
In [6]: django.__file__
Out[6]: '/Users/ugur/.virtualenvs/evernote/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init_
_.py'

In [7]: django.__package__
Out[7]: 'django'

In [8]:
```

What (else) is the purpose of this file `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have the following layout:

```
my_package/
   __init__.py
   my_module.py
```

Then a blank `__init__.py` would require that you write

```
 import my_package.my_module
 my_package.my_module.hello()
```

But you can put executable code into `__init__.py` which is executed as soon as you `import my_package`.

For example if you put

```
 # __init__.py
 import my_module
```

into `__init__.py` you can now simplfy your import:

```
 import my_package
 my_package.my_module.hello()
```

And you could further modify `__init__.py`:

```
 # __init__.py
 from my_module import hello
```

so that

```
 import my_package
 my_package.hello()
```

works.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you.